# file_exists() acting weird

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to pull some data out of a csv file but I'm stuck because `file_exists()` says the file doesn't exist when used with `get_template_directory_uri()`.

This is the short code:

```
function getPeopleNumber() {
    $csv = get_template_directory_uri().'/report/report.csv';
    $delimiter=',';
    if(!file_exists($csv) || !is_readable($csv)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $header = NULL;
    $data = array();
    if (($handle = fopen($csv, 'r')) !== FALSE) {
        while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, $delimiter)) !== FALSE) {
            if(!$header) {
                $header = $row;
            }
            else $data[] = array_combine($header, $row);
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
    return $csv;
}
```

If I `echo $csv` there's the complete (and correct) path.

But still the function returns `FALSE`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: maybe it's not readable by the web server?

Comment: @Fayaz well I've set all the permissions and both the file and webserver are on localhost

Comment: did you try with `get_template_directory()` as I suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `get_template_directory_uri()`, that's URL, not PATH.

Instead use `get_template_directory()`, that'll return PATH. Like:

```
$csv = get_template_directory() . '/report/report.csv';
```

Comment: correct answer. Stupid mistake made by copy and paste :S. Thank you!