# Why does my file_exist check fail?

Tags: plugins, themes

So basically, I'm trying to check if the user wants to overwrite my plugin template in his theme.

I have a plugin with a Custom Post Type 'links'. According to WP template system my archive file is 'archive-links.php'.

**So, why does my check for the file 'archive-links.php' in the template folder always return false?**

```
if(is_post_type_archive('links')) {

    $file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-links.php';

    if(file_exists($file)) {
        // echo('working');
        // template overwrite
        return get_template_directory_uri() . '/archive-links.php';
    } else {
        // echo('not working');
        // default plugin archive file
        return plugin_dir_path(__DIR__) . 'templates/archive-links.php';
    }
}
```

Comment: Which file is that code located in? Is it in the main folder of your plugin? Can you expand your code block to include the entire function? I'm assuming this is a filter but the `add_filter` call is missing as is the function name etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_exists() acting weird](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258556/file-exists-acting-weird)

Answer (score 2):

`get_template_directory_uri` doesn't return the directory name, it returns the URL of the directory. `file_exists` needs a file path, not a file URL.

Use `get_template_directory` instead, and don't forget to check `get_stylesheet_directory` too for those using child themes